# Blender 2.6 rock cycle render nodes problem in Blender 2.73

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I just bought a texture cookbook tutorial of how to create realistic textures using blender cycles and I was doing a tutorial on how to create a realistic stone. However, I ended up with something I really don't expect. The book showed the supposed finished product however, my finished product don't looked as nearly as it should be. I did everything else fine, just the stone. Here is my finished product.

[image: My finished product for the stone]

I am using a different version of Blender so that might be the problem, however, it feels like I made a mistake somewhere(remember, I am creating a different stone colour using the book's instruction). Here would be the nodes for this stone according to the book.

[image: First Bump]
[image: Second Bump]
[image: Colours]
[image: Other stuff needed for textures]

If anyone has any suggestions on improving this rock, please tell me. It would also help if someone has the same textures cookbook.(its Blender 2.6 Cycles: Materials and Textures Cookbook by Enrico Valenza.)

Comment: There should be CD with this book included, which containes Codes archive. Opening it you can find folders with starter (..._codes)  and complete (..._blends) files.

Comment: Ohhhh, I bought it from a secondhand shop. Its in mint condition though. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: The .blend files are available [here](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781782161301/tree/ee9ecd65f0daec5d12fedc0d931e0d88c07b341f), but don't expect them to match the explanations given in the book (which are on the other side limited to boring "[connect this output of this node to this input of this other node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHQG8.png)", without the reason for). Be prepared to investigate any problem on your own. After hours of tweaking, I found the scale in the mapping node has to be changed (e.g. from 1 to 3), else the material is closer to mud than to stone.